# Issue with \else in "biblatex"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, overleaf

I am using a .zip for a PhD template, and it contains too many files. So when I am trying to cite a reference I find that my compiler "livetex" and I am using TeXStudio is having trouble with:

```
\ifmc@nobind
    \usepackage[
        style=ieee,
        isbn=false,
        url=true,
        defernumbers]{biblatex}
\else
        \usepackage[
       style=ieee,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        url=false,
        defernumbers]{biblatex}
\fi
```

And it highlights that the error is on the `\else` line with the statement:

```
                      "Option clash for package biblatex. \else"
```

I don't understand because, for example, the file in Overleaf works fine.

Comment: Overleaf is notorious for hiding error messages and still producing output despite an error (see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864). So the mere fact that the document appears to work fine on Overleaf does not mean it actually does. It's hard to help you without seeing an actual example document that reproduces the error. Maybe you or your template already load `biblatex` in a different place with other options.

Comment: In general my experience has shown that "PhD templates" can be a huge pain. If you have to use this template because your institution requires it, they should also have someone maintain the template and offer support: Contact them about this issue. If you are not forced to use this template, consider using a simpler template or no template at all. (The fact alone that you say it contains too many files, shows the template is not really user friendly.)

Comment: the thing that was missing was to run in a terminal : biber thesis.bcf ; and then I succeded to show the references but now the are all have the number [0]

Comment: Indeed Overleaf runs Biber for you. If you compile on your own machine, you or your editor have to take care of that. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber for you. Run LaTeX again at least twice after you ran Biber. For documents compiling without error that should be enough. If your document errors though, this may not help. Errors should really be resolved even if they appear not to be problematic.

Comment: I tried with Overleaf and it told me `\ifmc@nobind` is not defined. Could you please complete your minimal example?

Comment: @moewe Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here :) Note that we have a Stop On First Error compiler option (in the Recompile menu) that can be recommended in cases where it's believed the default option is causing troubles. See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_the_Stop_on_First_Error_compilation_mode or https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-stop-on-first-error-compilation-mode for more details. Thanks!